# Following snippet doesn't produce expected result

Tags: java, operators, increment, operator-precedence

I found this in one of the Java programming quiz question.

```html
public class Calculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    System.out.print(i++ + c.opearation(i));
    System.out.print(i);
  }
  public int operation(int i) {
    System.out.print(i++);
    return i;
  }
}
```

Executing above snippet gives me the result of `121`. I'm expecting it to be `111`. I'll explain how I interpreted it.

`+` addition operator would get executed from right to left (ref: [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)). So, `c.operation(0)` is invoked first and it prints the value `1` instead I'm expecting the value to be `0` since `System.out.print` prints the value of `i` first and then increments the i value since it is a post increment operator.

Secondly, the `i` value 1 is returned to the main and the statement `System.out.print(i++ + 1)` gets executed now. And since `i` has post increment operator it should have executed like `0 + 1` and produced the result `1` insted it printed result as `2`.

Thirdly, the `i` value is now incremented to `1` and this gets printed as expected.

In short, I'm expecting the value to be printed as `011` but I got the result as `121`. I'm not sure where my interpretation goes wrong.

Comment: You got the precedence of `+` wrong. Look at the linked document at level 11 (the addition operator, _not_ the unary `+`): there it states they are executed "left to right", i.e. _first_ `i++` and _then_ operation(i)` which now will get 1.

Comment: You are right @Thomas. Thank you for pointing it out !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)

> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically
>   left-associative (they group left-to-right).

---

```
int i = 0;
System.out.print(i++ + c.operation(i));
```

1. evaluate `i++`, get left operand `0`, and increment `i` to `1`.
2. pass `i(1)` to `c.operation(i)`,  execute `System.out.print(i++)`.  **Print `1`** then return `2`(right operand).
3. `i++ + c.operation(i) ---> 0 + 2`, **print `2`**.
4. **print `1`**.